# dereference an integer pointer on 64 bit platform

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

if we dereference an integer pointer, say * (int * )
as we know that integer pointer dominate 8 byte in 64 platform. but integer still takes 4 byte in 64 platform.

what if i want to dereference an pointer where the beginning of its memory contains another pointer address. so actually i want to take the value of the first 8 bytes. will dereference * (int *) get 4 byte or 8byte? i think it should be 4 byte as integer is 4 byte. but how can i get 8 byte in 64 bit platform? without knowing whether the platform is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow. Can you give us a small code snippet as an exemple?

Comment: If the "beginning of its memory contains another pointer address" you need to dereference into it via a pointer to pointer, not a pointer to int. If the "thing" at some address is another address, then a pointer to pointer is the only logical way to get to (and eventually *through*) it. All of that said, this has an almost-overwhelming pungent aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *really* doing, and how did you get to this menagerie as your mechanism for solving it?

Comment: if you're trying to force use of 8 bytes, you can use `int64_t` instead of `int`

Comment: Seems like you want a pointer to a pointer. Or a pointer to a 64-bit integer type. Be clear.

Comment: It does not matter how long the pointer itself is unless you want just assign the integer "address" value to it as it often done in the embedded programming. But even then it is easy to avoid problems using fixed length integers like uint64_t

Comment: You dereference a pointer to the size you want by originally defining it as a pointer to the type you need. But "i want to take the value of the first 8 bytes" suggests you might want to point to a `char` array.

Answer (score 4):

Lets make some things clear (these are all platform independent but in MOST cases), if on your system:

```
sizeof(int) is 4 bytes
sizeof(int*) is 4 on 32bit and 8 on 64bit
sizeof(int**) is 4 on 32bit and 8 on 64bit
```

When you dereference an `int*`, you are extracting an `int`. The original `int*` may be 8 bytes on a 64bit but you will get 4 bytes from either 32bit or 64bit systems.

When you dereference an `int**`, you are extracting an `int*`. The original `int**` may be 4 bytes on 32bit or 8 bytes on a 64bit, but you will get 4 bytes from a 32bit system and 8 bytes from a 64bit system because you are extracting `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem right, but actually I think that you really don't have a problem at all, because the compiler will handle word sizes automatically for you, generating the proper code for each platform. So let's assume that you call a function that returns a pointer to a pointer to an int:

```
int** ppiValue = SomeFunction ();
```

If you dereference this pointer, you get a pointer to an int, which will have the proper size on each platform:

```
int* piValue = *ppiValue;
```

This will be 8 bytes on a 64-bit processor, or 4 bytes on a 32-bit processor. The compiler is responsible for choosing the right size for the selected target platform. Now let's dereference this pointer:

```
int iValue = *piValue;
```

This will be a 4-byte value on both processors. Once again, the compiler is responsible for generating proper machine code instructions.

So don't bother - as long as you rely on strong typing and don't use dangerous typecasts, the compiler will take care of the low-level indirection details.